Object count is different between --bare cloned and --set-upstream remote object
I am trying to mirror a repo from Azure to Gitlab. Following is the log;
myself@PC:~/REPO$ git clone <REPO ADDRESS --bare
Cloning into bare repository 'repo.git'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 434337 objects to send. (1130 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (434337/434337), 821.82 MiB | 4.85 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (299404/299404), done.
myself@PC:~/REPO$

However, when i try to push it to upstream there is a huge difference between Object count;
myself@PC:~/REPO/repo.git$ git push --set-upstream new_origin --all
Enumerating objects: 68459, done.
Counting objects: 100% (68459/68459), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (20123/20123), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68459/68459), 293.86 MiB | 157.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 68459 (delta 47199), reused 68459 (delta 47199), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (47199/47199), done.

Why is that? Any help or if let me know if require further information.
I am expecting the object counts to be same.

Hi @user3660152, have you checked the answer below? I wonder to know if it is helpful for you or you have any question.

It seems that it is due to how Git handles objects during the push process. When you clone a repository, Git fetches all objects, including blobs, trees, and commits. However, when you push to a new remote, Git only pushes the objects that are necessary to recreate the branches and tags you’re pushing. Here are some possible reasons why you see different objects.

Packfile Optimization: Git optimizes the packfile during the push, which can result in fewer objects being sent. This optimization includes delta compression, which reduces the number of objects by storing differences between similar objects
Unreferenced Objects: The original repository might contain unreferenced objects (e.g., objects that are not reachable from any branch or tag). These objects are not pushed to the new remote

You can see the detailed explanation from this question Git: push all objects to remote repository (not just refs, but absolutely all blobs, trees and commits).
